# Геометрическая фигура на HTML/CSS

Tags: css, html

Как сделать на HTML/CSS такую геометрическую фигуру?

В сети нашел метод с помощью `clip-path` и псевдоэлемента, задавая ему нулевую ширину/высоту, стилизуя `border`. Есть ли ещё способы?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а сами то что сделали ? что уже реализовали и в чём вас не устроило то что есть в сети ?здесь не фрилансе и здесь помогут только если вы сами что то пытались сделать ...а до этих пор это обычное либо учебное задание либо попытка получить на халяву готовое

Comment: Это не учебное задание, и не попытка получить халяву, сам я разобрался с вышеуказанными способами, но внутреннее я говорит что должен быть еще метод, поэтому и задаю такой вопрос, чтобы поощрить свое либидо

Comment: хм.... тогда svg хороший способ ... вы всё таки покажите что сделали ... фотки не надо ... код: html css или что там у вас ..

Comment: html <body>
 <div class="container">
  <div class="car1">
  hello
  </div>
 </div>

Comment: css .car1{
 background-image:url(one.jpg);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size:cover;
 height: 600px;
 width: calc(100%-10px);
 clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 80%, 50% 100%, 0% 80%);
 border: 5px solid black;
}
.container{
 background-image:url(twy.jpg);
 background-position: center, bottom;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size:cover;
 height: 900px;
 width: 100%;
}

Comment: к сожалению нет я рассматривал этот способ, используя псевдо элементы не получиться сделать один общий фон, поэтому и задал этот вопрос тут, есть ли еще способы не используя псевдоэлементы и clip-path

Comment: спасибо, этот вариант интересный, буду изучать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Только верхняя часть

```css
html,body{
  height:100%;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1"  version="1.1"
viewBox="0 0 600 350">
        <pattern id="img1" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="1200px" height="600px">
            <image class='twombly' xlink:href="http://henlulu02.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/tesla.png" x="-200px" y="-100px"
                width="1200px" height="600px" />
        </pattern>
  
    <filter id="blur" x="0" y="0" x2="0%" y2="10px">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="6" />
    </filter>


     <linearGradient id="grad2" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="30%">
      <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,255,255);stop-opacity:0.1" />
      <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,255,255);stop-opacity:1" />
    </linearGradient>

  
  <polygon points="300,350 0,200 0,0 600,0 600,200"; style="fill:url(#img1);"/>

  <polygon points="300,300 0,150 600,150" style="fill:url(#grad2);transform:translate(0,50px);" filter="url(#blur)"/>
  
</>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.triangle {
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #20a3bf;
  position: relative;
}

.triangle:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 100%;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 50px solid #20a3bf;
  border-left: 250px solid transparent;
  border-right: 250px solid transparent;
}

.square {
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-top: 70px;
  background: #20a3bf;
  position: relative;
}

.square:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: -50px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-bottom: 50px solid #20a3bf;
  border-right: 250px solid transparent;
}

.square:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: -50px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-bottom: 50px solid #20a3bf;
  border-left: 250px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="triangle"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
```

Comment: Но где же адаптивность? `SVG` в этом случае значительно сильнее